# Killing non-waiting thread

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me, rim-4.2

I need to kill specific worker thread in my application. I don't have any control over its execution, which means I cannot employ classic signal boolean variable approach. This thread is non-waiting. It doesn't sleep or wait on some monitor to be signalled - I can't interrupt it via Thread.interrupt, this throws IllegalThreadState exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, at least not without killing the entire MIDlet.